Checkbox is checked but returns false
I would like to use some JS to perform a function if a checkbox is checked. However, my input field checkbox keeps returning false when it's checked and I can't understand why.
Here's the HTML:
<input id="option_service_desk" type="checkbox"/>

Here's the JS:
if (document.getElementById('option_service_desk').checked)
 { 
 console.log('service 247 checked');
} else {
 console.log("service 247 not checked");
}

I've tried checking in the console and indeed, it's returning as false, even though it is checked on the screen.


can't duplicate the issue - when do you run the code?

I'm running the code in the console after checking/unchecking the checkbox.

then you're doing something odd - the code works fine

hmm....fair play, thank you for letting me know the script is at least ok.

Make sure you don't have multiple checkboxes  (or elements) with the same id in your HTML

try to test the code in Incognito as browser extensions mostly cause wrong result or code block.

I've double-checked - it's just the one instance of the ID. Incognito doesn't make a difference here. I am fully bamboozled by this and have been going mad for the last 4 hours.
